# Php : Mysqli - Data Type and Where Conditions with Multiple ID

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have table product

```
id |  Name |  catid  |

1  |  A    |    2
2  |  B    |    2
3  |  c    |    2
4  |  D    |    2
5  |  ch   |    2
7  |  kj   |    2
```

where id is primary key of product table

Above id get reopen multiple time

reopen table :

```
re_id |  testName      |  catid  |  product_id  |

1     |  not okk       |    2    |   1,2,3,4    |
2     |  not okk       |    2    |   5,7        |
```

where re_id is primary key

I want .. can i insert  multiple value ( how i have shown 1,2,3,4)  so that i can get list with WHERE IN condition.

Want to know its safe to use such condition in DB

How i can insert multiple id in single field. and what should be data type

**Update :**

**Below is possible ?**

```
"INSERT INTO reopen (testname,catid,product_id) VALUES ('not okk','2','1,2,3,4') "

AND

"SELECT * FROM reopen WHERE product_id IN (1,2,3,4)"
```

Comment: you can use normal varchar type to store it, but you need to maintain this csv list on your own and you can use FIND_IN_SET function of mysql to associate product id with product rows

Comment: thanks HRK , for FIND_IN_SET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use native support of referental integrity, you may store a list of values in a varchar field.

In my oppinion it is much better to (follow canonical way) create one more table for multiple links between **reopen.id** and **product.id**.

```
reopen_id | product_id
----------+-----------
1         | 1
1         | 2
1         | 3
1         | 4
2         | 5
2         | 7
```

By adding composite key on both fields you make duplicate links impossible. To insers data you may use multiple-row insert command `INSERRT INTO links (1,1),(1,2)…`

For WHERE-conditions you may use normal IN operator

You do not need any text manipulations and it makes queries faster

There is no any limitation to a number of values in the list.

Storage is more optimal in this case

**UPDATE:**

See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93884/5)

Comment: @user3209031, please note, it's a feature of MySQL only. Do not work in other databases.

Comment: @user3209031 I've created [SQLFiddle for this question](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93884/5)

Answer (score 0):

You have asked several questions:

## How to generate the reopen table?

first get the data in sql:
select id from product where ...your condition...

second:
with the result array, do an php implode:
$product_id=implode(",",resultarray);

and then insert it to the reopen table using sql insert.

## Can you access the id's in reopen using sql WHERE in?

No, unfortunately the SQL IN operator can ony work on
either single numbers oder single string values, not on
combined stringe as in your case.

## How to proceed?

Just use the product table:
Make an inner select to get the reopen-rows and
then use the WHERE IN condition in the outer select:

```
select id from product where id in ( 
    select id from product where ...your condition...
)
```

Comment: thanks Wesee , dude reopen table is with agree and disagree function , hence 1,2,3,4 id may be agree and again may be disagree or vise versa ... hence each time i have to check with ID